# Auto-generate class is not updating with build_runner

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using a **build_runner** to generate auto-generated code in the flutter project.

Issue: When I make an update in the model class and then I try to run below command, but it does not update auto-generated class.

Command:

```
pub run build_runner build
```

Dart Packages:

```
built_value: '>=5.5.5 <7.0.0'

build_runner: ^1.5.0

built_value_generator: ^6.6.0
```

After the execution of the command for **build_runner**, an auto-generated class should be updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When it conflicts with current generated classes, it may possible that it will not  update the generated classes. So I have tested with below command and it's working fine.

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

This will delete current conflict files and recreate as per the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `watch` sub-command to Continuous generation of code.

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner watch
```

It runs a persistent build server that watches the files system for edits and does rebuilds as necessary.